# Python get time at specify GMT

Tags: python, django, datetime, gmt

I am trying to get the current time at a specific GMT ( like +3 -1 etc.). I have a script that runs on a remote server, and he needs to update the current time at another country which I can not find at the time_zone list. I tried

```
import pytz
pytz.all_timezones
```

And look for the country and find it in the list; I know the county GMT is +3.

```
import datetime 
from django.utils.timezone import now
```

both now function is relevant to me, and I can not find how I find the now function with GMT +3

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain localized time is via `timezone.localtime`

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.localtime(timezone=pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
```

If you already have a datetime object, you can use `datetime.astimezone` or again, the `timezone.localtime`

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()

now.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
timezone.localtime(now, pytz.timezone('Asia/Jerusalem'))
```

If you want to get the local timezone of a machine, you can run the following. However, I believe there is no magic, and the server must be configured appropriately for this to work.

```
import time
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.localtime(timezone=pytz.timezone(time.tzname[0]))
```

I've tried tn on AWS EC2 which I have access to, and it just has `UTC` set, so it's still mostly up to you to specify the desired timezone.

Comment: The problem is that my country is not on the list, so I can not choose it, and I am looking for a general solution

Comment: well, it is the general solution, just replace the timezone name with the correct one. Which country is that?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Does that help? @shaked

Comment: Isreal currently but I need that my script will use general time zone, cause some scripts will run in GMT +5 ect

Comment: The timezone is 'Asia/Jerusalem'. Often the country name is not included in timezone name, and it is not obvious which city is take into account (e.g. in my country: Microsoft uses Bern, Unix derivates uses Zurich).

Comment: @shaked can you be more specific? what does "general time zone" mean to you? If you mean that the script should be configurable, the last solution in the response is one way to do it. Another way is to provide a timezone name through the env variables. But that's actually another question - I believe I've provided the answer to the original question of "how to get a local timezone", please **accept** if I was able to help

Comment: So I need to get a parameter which can be number (+-5) and get the current time in this GMT. So it can be +3 for Isreal or -4 for NY

Comment: Get how? As a function argument?